# Write the given expression as an algebraic expression in $x$. $\cos (2{\tan ^{ - 1}}x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My answer is $\large\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$?

Am I right?

Comment: Why not show us how you got there? Also, if you're going to use this site regularly, I'd suggest you invest some time in learning how to format mathematics here. There are links to help available on this page.

Comment: Specifically, the [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You may want to read up  on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) as well.

Comment: Set $\tan^{-1}x=\theta\implies\tan\theta=x, \cos2\theta=\frac{1-\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$

Answer (score 3):

First, note that $$\cos (2{\tan ^{ - 1}}x) = 2co{s^2}({\tan ^{ - 1}}x) - 1$$ now, you should evaluate the R.H.S. in terms of x. To do so, visualize the triangle below
[image]

note that if we consider the angle between the side with length 1 and the chord to be $$\theta$$, then $$\tan \theta  = x$$ also note that according to the Pythagorean theorem, the length of the chord is $$\sqrt {1 + {x^2}}$$ so that $$\cos \theta  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {x^2}} }}$$ Summarizing, the answer to your question would be $$\cos (2{\tan ^{ - 1}}x) = 2\frac{1}{{1 + {x^2}}} - 1 = \frac{{1 - {x^2}}}{{1 + {x^2}}}$$